# Назначение глагола "было"

Tags: синтаксис

"Со страху я чуть было не подавился вареником". Какую роль тут играет глагол "было"? Может, это устаревшая форма письма? А если так можно говорить, то надо ли выделять "было" запятыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Какую роль тут играет глагол "было"?

Написание такое вполне современно, и "было" здесь действительно по современным понятиям явно не глагол, но вот насчет роли... По большому счету - никакой. Модальная функция вполне реализуется частицей "чуть", а усилительная тут не нужна, ибо и так ясно, что действие не закончено или не доведено до конца. Тем самым ставится под сомнение тезис о том, что "было" здесь *самостоятельная* частица.

В ряде словарей (Толковый Ефремовой, например, и словарь-справочник Пахомова,Свинцова, Филатова) все сочетание "чуть было не" трактуется как *неделимая* частица со значением "едва не". Я вполне разделяю этот подход.

Никаких знаков препинания ни внутри, ни вокруг себя не требует.

Answer (score 5):

В данном примере **было** не глагол, а частица. Вот что говорит *Русская грамматика* (параграф 1694):

> Частица **было** вносит в предложение
> значение действия осуществившегося, но
> или прерванного, не доведенного до
> конца, или не приведшего к желаемому
> результату, не достигшего цели. Эта
> частица сочетается с глаголом в форме
> прош. вр. или вводится в предложение с
> общим значением прошедшего: Акакий
> Акакиевич еще было насчет починки, но
> Петрович не дослышал (Гоголь); Он было
> пошел. - Постой, постой! Куда ты? -
> остановил его Обломов (Гонч.); Повозка
> было тронулась; но он остановил ее (Л.
> Толст.). Частица было соединяется
> также с причастиями прош. вр. и
> деепричастиями сов. вида: собравшиеся
> было уходить; решившись было остаться.

Запятыми выделять не надо.

Comment: Спасибо Вам,@stopkran. Ответ @tmp мне показался несколько более полным,более соответствующим моему пониманию ответа на этот вопрос. Извините.

Comment: Да не за что! :-) Я согласен. У @tmp опыт больше, он дал более точный ответ.

Comment: @post, я успел прочитать написанное до меня, это избавило меня от необходимости писать многословное введение и позволило сразу перейти к сути.  
Так что слава -- пополам.   
А вообще здесь не особо принято извиняться по таким поводам... так что в обратной ситуации можете не церемониться. Или, если уж есть такое желание, конкретизируйте, чем именно один ответ лучше, кроме субъективной оцекуи.